# Getting Last Week Score using Javascript Facebook Scores & Achievements API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to post user score using `HTTP POST` request to `/USER_ID/scores`
and Get user and their friends total score by issuing an HTTP GET request to/APP_ID/scores

I have read all the Facebook Developer doc related to Score and Achievements API, can't find any idea to Get last week scores.

How can i get user and their friends Last Week scores ?

Comment: That is not possible. Scores API is for overall scores only, there is no way to select by date. If you want that, you have to implement it on your end.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I will try to implement it on my end